# Type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a member `Aggregate' and the best extension method overload

Tags: c#, .net, linq, constants

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong with

```
private const long _divisor = // 10^9 - 7
        Enumerable.Repeat(10, 9).Aggregate(1, (p, i) => p * i) - 7;
```

??

Getting the error

> Type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a
>   member`Aggregate' and the best extension method overload
>   `System.Linq.Enumerable.Aggregate(this
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, int, System.Func)' has some
>   invalid arguments !Anonymous methods and lambda expressions cannot be
>   used in the current context

and I feel like I'm following exactly the documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Are you missing the relevant `using` statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> lambda expressions cannot be used in the current context

You are specifying `const` on a non-primitive value, the compiler won't allow it.

Either remove the `const` specifier or place a primitive value.

```
private const long _divisor =  (long)(10e9 - 7); // Or just write 9999999993 instead
```